# Python: Slicing a dataframe by a list returns a longer list than expected

Tags: python, multi-index, numpy-slicing

I have a list of 517 tuples. When I use that list to slice my dataframe using .loc, somehow there are 518 rows. If it's important, these are 517 tuples of a multi-index. Visual examination of the result appears to have no obvious header or null rows.

```
print(submatrix2.shape)
x = list(get_list_of_university_towns().itertuples(index=False, name=None))
print(len(x))
univ_matrix = submatrix2.loc[x,] 
print(univ_matrix.shape)
```

Outputs:

```
(10730, 1)
517
(518,1)
```

What could be causing this mismatch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a duplicate index, which allows your final shape to be greater than your passed list.

Reproducible example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'vals':["a", "b", "c", "d"],
                   'n':[0,1,1,2]})

df = df.set_index('n')


    vals
n   
0   a
1   b
1   c
2   d
```

Now

```
>>> x=[0,1,2];len(x)
3
>>> df.loc[x,:].shape
(4, 1)
```

Comment: The multi-index is State, Region. It seems a little impossible that in the full dataset would be two regions in the same state with the same name.

Comment: Also, your example doesn't use tuples to call a multi-index.

Comment: Welp, you were correct. Two clinton, New York. Probably there for me to discover this for myself. Thanks for being right.